# How to read data from specific cassandra node

Tags: cassandra, hector

I want to fetch all data from column family using Hector Range Query.
In order to parallize the reading i look for a way to work (in parallel) against each node and fetch only his own data (i.e. not using it as a coordinator to all nodes).
Any ideas?

Comment: I think you are only breaking the way Cassandra manages consistency. And if you want to only wait for one node you can read with Consistency ONE. To do exactly what you want you will have to do your own Cassandra fork since the behaviour you are trying to override is in Cassandra (not the client side).

Answer (score 0):

You should use Cassandra's [Hadoop support](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/HadoopSupport) instead of reinventing that in Hector.